# Excel unable to open file xlsxwriter python

Tags: python, xml, excel, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I am trying to generate report in Excel Table using Excel file.

After generating Excel file, when i try to open, it says "unable to read content" and Removed Feature: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (table)

Above is not causing any issue to either to template/data but warning is my concern

Below is code:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[10]:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import datetime
import xlsxwriter
import time
import pytz
import os
import sys




# func to get diff in days
def days_between(d1, d2):
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)

Aged_tickets_list = []
Aged_index = []
days_diff = 0
Aged_tickets_count = 0
smarts_alerts_Aged = 0
total_waiting_user_cases = 0
total_smarts_cases = 0
total_awaiting_3rd = 0
sev2_cases = 0
sev3_cases = 0
Aged_tickets_Count_5_10 = 0
Aged_tickets_Count_10_15 = 0
Aged_tickets_Count_15 = 0
closed_mis = 0
ongoing_mis = 0
sev2_au_cases = 0
sev2_a3rd_cases = 0
sev2_assigned_cases = 0

# time format on handoff template
format = "%a %b %d %H:%M %Y %Z"
my_date = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
time_pst= my_date.strftime(format)

# code to load excel file
#table = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\v-ajmudi\\Desktop\\Python_GNS3\\incident.xlsx',sheetname='Page 1',header=0)

user_input = input("Enter path of your incident excel file :")
assert os.path.exists(user_input), "I did not find the file at, "+str(user_input)
print("Hooray we found your file!")
ext = os.path.splitext(user_input)[-1].lower()
if ext == '.xlsx' or ext == '.xls' :
    table = pd.read_excel(user_input,header=0)

else :
    print (" Provide valid Excel File")
    sys.exit()

# formatting current_time to format str and then to datetime format
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
datetime_current_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(current_time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# iterating over table file
for y in range(len(table)):
    if (table['State'][y] == 'Awaiting User'):
        total_waiting_user_cases = total_waiting_user_cases + 1
    if (table['Caller'][y] == 'SMARTS '): 
        total_smarts_cases = total_smarts_cases + 1
    if (table['State'][y] == 'Awaiting 3rd Party'):
        total_awaiting_3rd = total_awaiting_3rd + 1
    if (table['Severity'][y] == '2 - High'):
        sev2_cases = sev2_cases + 1
        if (table['State'][y] == 'Awaiting User' ):
            sev2_au_cases = sev2_au_cases + 1
        if (table['State'][y] == 'Awaiting 3rd Party'):
            sev2_a3rd_cases = sev2_a3rd_cases + 1
        if (table['State'][y] == 'Assigned'):
            sev2_assigned_cases = sev2_assigned_cases + 1

    if (table['Severity'][y] == '3 - Medium'):
        sev3_cases = sev3_cases + 1
    if (table['Severity'][y] == '1 - Managed') or (table['Severity'][y] == '0 - Major'):
        ongoing_mis = ongoing_mis + 1

# iteration over index,rows. count = days diff   
for index,rows in table.iterrows():
    days_diff = days_between(datetime_current_time,table['Opened'][index])
    if days_diff > 5:
        Aged_tickets_count = Aged_tickets_count + 1
        Aged_tickets_list.append(table['Number'][index])
        Aged_index.append(index)
    if days_diff >5 and days_diff <= 10:
        Aged_tickets_Count_5_10 = Aged_tickets_Count_5_10 + 1
    if days_diff >10 and days_diff <= 15:
        Aged_tickets_Count_10_15 = Aged_tickets_Count_10_15 + 1
    if days_diff > 15:
        Aged_tickets_Count_15 = Aged_tickets_Count_15 + 1

# printing INC/Caller/current INC state
for x in Aged_index:
   ## print ((table['Number'][x])+("   ")+(table['Caller'][x])+ ("      ")+(table['State'][x]))
    if table['Caller'][x] == 'SMARTS ':
       ## print ("Smarts Aged tickets:", table['Number'][x])
        smarts_alerts_Aged = smarts_alerts_Aged + 1

##for x in Aged_index:
   ## if (table['State'][x] == 'Awaiting User') and (table['Caller'][x] == 'SMARTS '):
      ## print("SMARTS Aged tickets in Awaiting User state:",table['Number'][x])

print ("Total Tickets:",len(table))
print ("Cases with Awaiting user state:",total_waiting_user_cases)
print ("Cases with Awaiting 3rd Party state:",total_awaiting_3rd)
print ("No of SMARTS cases:",total_smarts_cases)
print ("Total Sev2 cases:",sev2_cases)
print("Total Sev3 cases: ", sev3_cases)
#print (table[['Caller','Number']])
print ("Tickets more than 5 days: ", Aged_tickets_count)
print ("Smarts aged cases:", smarts_alerts_Aged)
print("Aged case > 15:",Aged_tickets_Count_15)
print (sev2_au_cases)
print (sev2_a3rd_cases)
sev2_cases_info = (("Ongoing Sev2 Tickets:- Awaiting user - {}, 3rd Party Pending - {}, In Progress - {}").format(sev2_au_cases,sev2_a3rd_cases,sev2_assigned_cases))
print (sev2_cases_info)


# In[11]:

# create workbook and add sheet
# sheet to display values
# sheet2 to generate report
incident_excel_file = xlsxwriter.Workbook("incidents_excel.xlsx")
incident_sheet = incident_excel_file.add_worksheet(name="incidents")
incident_sheet2 = incident_excel_file.add_worksheet(name="Handoff Template")
incident_excel_file.set_size(100,100)
incident_sheet.set_column(0,4,25)
incident_sheet2.set_column(0,15,15)
incident_sheet3 = incident_excel_file.add_worksheet()
incident_sheet3.set_column(0,1)

row = 0
col = 0
# Data for excel sheet
data_excel = (
    ['Total tickets',(len(table))],
    ["Awaiting user cases",total_waiting_user_cases],
    ["Alerts",total_smarts_cases],
    ["Awaiting 3rd Party cases",total_awaiting_3rd],
    ['Sev 2 cases',sev2_cases],
    ['Sev3 cases',sev3_cases],
    ["Aged tickets >5", Aged_tickets_count],
    ["Aged tickets > 15",Aged_tickets_Count_15],
    ["Aged tickets 5-10",Aged_tickets_Count_5_10],
    ["Aged ticket 10-15",Aged_tickets_Count_10_15])

# Add a bold format for cells
bold = incident_excel_file.add_format()
bold.set_color('blue')
bold.set_size
bold.set_bold()

#incident_sheet.insert_textbox('F2', text, options)

for x,y in data_excel:
    incident_sheet.write(row,col,x,bold)
    incident_sheet.write(row,col+1,y)
    row += 1


# In[12]:

format_table = incident_excel_file.add_format()
format_table.set_border(2)
# adding table to sheet2
incident_sheet2.add_table('A1:L17',{'header_row': False})

# values for template
prepared_by = input("Prepared by ?")
handoff_to = input("Handoff to ?")
closed_mis = input("No of closed MIs ?")
new_tickets = input("No of New Tickets during shift ?")
closed_tickets = input("No of closed tickets during shift ?")
smart_cases = "Total smart cases:" + str(total_smarts_cases)
prepared_by_whom = "Prepared by: "+ prepared_by
handoff_to_whom = "Handoff to: "+handoff_to
handoff_time = "Date & Time: " + time_pst

# cell formats and properties of columns/rows
format_basic = incident_excel_file.add_format({'align':'center'})
format_1 = incident_excel_file.add_format({'align':'center','border':0,'bg_color':'#7FFF00','font_size':20})
format_2 = incident_excel_file.add_format({'align':'center','border':0,'bg_color':'white','font_size':15})
format_3 = incident_excel_file.add_format({'align':'center','border':0,'bg_color':'#7B68EE','font_size':15})
format_4 = incident_excel_file.add_format({'align':'center','border':0,'bg_color':'#FFFF99','num_format':'@'})

incident_sheet2.hide_gridlines(2)
incident_sheet2.set_column('M:V',None,None,{'hidden': True})
incident_sheet2.set_default_row(25,hide_unused_rows=True)
incident_sheet2.write("B2",prepared_by_whom)
incident_sheet2.write ("K2",handoff_to_whom)
incident_sheet2.set_row(11,None,format_4)
incident_sheet2.set_row(12,None,format_4)
incident_sheet2.set_row(13,None,format_4)
incident_sheet2.set_row(14,None,format_4)

# merging and writing data to cells
incident_sheet2.merge_range('E2:G2',handoff_time,format_basic)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('A1:L1','Service Operations - Network Infrastructure Shift Handover Report',format_1)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('A3:L3',"Significant Incident/Events During Shift",format_3)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('A6:L6',"Summary of MI and Impacting Sev2 (Ongoing & Closed)",format_3)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('B4:C4',"Closed MIs",format_basic)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('B5:C5',"Ongoing/Open MIs",format_basic)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('I4:J4',"Ongoing/Open Sev2",format_basic)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('I5:J5',"Ongoing/Open Sev3",format_basic)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('A7:L7',sev2_cases_info,format_basic)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('A8:L8',"MI/Scheduled Tickets info",format_basic)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('A9:L9','',format_basic)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('A10:L10','',format_basic)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('A11:L11',"Handover Ticket Details",format_3)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('B12:C12',"Overall Queue Size",format_4)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('B13:C13','New tickets during shift',format_4)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('B14:C14','Closed tickets during shift',format_4)
incident_sheet2.merge_range('G12:H12',"Awaiting user/3rd Party pending",format_4)
incident_sheet2.write('H13','Tickets 06-10 Days',format_4)
incident_sheet2.write('H14','Tickets 11-15 Days',format_4)
incident_sheet2.write('H15','Tickets 16+ Days',format_4)
incident_sheet2.write('K4',sev2_cases,format_basic)
incident_sheet2.write('K5',sev3_cases,format_basic)
incident_sheet2.write('D4',int(closed_mis),format_basic)
incident_sheet2.write('D5',ongoing_mis,format_basic)
incident_sheet2.write('D12',(len(table)))
incident_sheet2.write('I13',Aged_tickets_Count_5_10)
incident_sheet2.write('I14',Aged_tickets_Count_10_15)
incident_sheet2.write('I15',Aged_tickets_Count_15)
incident_sheet2.write('D13',int(new_tickets))
incident_sheet2.write('D14',int(closed_tickets))
incident_sheet2.write('I12',"{}/{}".format(total_waiting_user_cases,total_awaiting_3rd))

# sheet close
incident_excel_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Excel error occurs when the XlsxWriter table has been corrupted in some way. The most common causes are overlapping tables or overwriting the header row. However, neither of those look like the case here.

At a guess I would say that it is probably the merge ranges that are added over the table. Excel doesn't allow regions of a table to be merged.

Note, you could identify exactly what is causing the issue leaving in the table but comment out the code that writes to the worksheet and then uncommenting sections, in a binary manner, until the error occurs again. And I would start with the merge ranges.